# Django Celery scheduled task no output

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I am working with Django and want a certain task to be runned twice a day (09:00 and 17:00).
So I found Celery on the internet, and it looks good. I followed a few tutorials, and set it up.

I've set a periodic task in the database, and it runs (for test) every minute. Or, it doesn't, it only says so:

```
[2020-12-15 14:32:34,997: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task ResumePentest (VulnManager.tasks.resumePentest)
[2020-12-15 14:32:34,998: DEBUG/MainProcess] VulnManager.tasks.resumePentest sent. id->277c73a8-58bc-41ea-b2ba-4aa7af0c8b94
```

I don't think it actually runs, because I've tried some different "debugging" options: create file, print text, run my actual command. None of them seems to be working.

My tasks.py file looks like this (for testing):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def resumePentest():
    f = open("/home/marvin/demofile2.txt", "a")
    f.write("Now the file has more content!")
    f.close()
```

I run the celery worker with this command:

```
celery -A VulnScanner beat -l DEBUG --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

Any hints? Not sure what I am doing wrong? If more info is needed, please let me know.

Full output of celery worker:

```
celery beat v5.0.4 (singularity) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2020-12-15 14:44:26
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,388: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,389: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,389: DEBUG/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: initial read
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,389: DEBUG/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,390: DEBUG/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Fetching database schedule
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,392: DEBUG/MainProcess] Using selector: EpollSelector
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,396: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<ModelEntry: ResumePentest VulnManager.tasks.resumePentest(*[], **{}) <freq: 1.00 minute>>
<ModelEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup(*[], **{}) <crontab: 0 4
         * *
          * (m/h/d/dM/MY), UTC>
        >
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,429: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 seconds
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,448: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {'capabilities': {'publisher_confirms': True, 'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, 'basic.nack': True, 'consumer_cancel_notify': True, 'connection.blocked': True, 'consumer_priorities': True, 'authentication_failure_close': True, 'per_consumer_qos': True, 'direct_reply_to': True}, 'cluster_name': 'rabbit@ubuntuserver', 'copyright': 'Copyright (c) 2007-2019 Pivotal Software, Inc.', 'information': 'Licensed under the MPL 1.1. Website: https://rabbitmq.com', 'platform': 'Erlang/OTP 22.2.7', 'product': 'RabbitMQ', 'version': '3.8.2'}, mechanisms: [b'PLAIN', b'AMQPLAIN'], locales: ['en_US']
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,449: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task ResumePentest (VulnManager.tasks.resumePentest)
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,455: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 1
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,457: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,459: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,459: DEBUG/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,467: DEBUG/MainProcess] VulnManager.tasks.resumePentest sent. id->d33fe09b-2e25-4f7b-aec9-03ea4a630ab9
[2020-12-15 14:44:26,469: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
[2020-12-15 14:44:31,477: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
^C[2020-12-15 14:44:33,765: DEBUG/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2020-12-15 14:44:33,766: DEBUG/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2020-12-15 14:44:33,766: DEBUG/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2020-12-15 14:44:33,766: DEBUG/MainProcess] Writing entries...
```

The final goal of using this is to start (at 9:00) and stop (at 17:00) a security scan using greenbone / gvm-cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this command for checking new task: `celery -A proj worker -l INFO`.

For a complete listing of the command-line options available, use the help command: `celery help`

Comment: This did it. I indeed needed the worker, but also the celery beat. Thanks for the help.